# Генерация sitemap(html) в wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, sitemap, wp-plugin

Подскажите пожалуйста решение для вывода карты сайта на основе меню.

Например есть меню:

```
Красота (рубрика id=1)
    Лицо (рубрика id=2)
    Лекарства (архив произвольного post_type)
    Тело (страница id=3)
```

Нужно вывести:

```
Красота (рубрика id=1)
    все записи рубрики id=1
    Лицо (рубрика id=2)
        все записи рубрики id=2
    Лекарства (архив произвольного post_type=example)
        все записи post_type=example
    Тело (страница id=3)
        все дочерние записи страницы id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

По примеру рубрик:

```
// Сначала получим все рубрики    
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    // Выведем ссылки на них
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link($term) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    // Под каждой рубрикой выведем цикл с ее записями
        $cat_posts = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $term->term_id ));
            while($cat_posts->have_posts()) {
                $cat_posts->the_post();
                echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">'. get_the_title() .'</a>';
            }
    }
```

Я не уверен что тут совсем багов нет, до конца не понятно как себя ведет вордпресс когда 1 запись находится в сразу нескольких рубриках... В данном случае она появляется цикле 2 раза если такое есть, нужно дописывать проверки и т.п.

Comment: Ну вообще то у меня задача **вывода карты сайта на основе меню**,
а вы выводите все категории, которых может и не быть в меню.

Comment: берите функцию отсюда, выводите подциклы с записями исходя из id существующих в меню https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/